# Null pointer exception in bufferedreader

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

In the sample code below, why does a null pointer exception get thrown when I try to get the value of string two? The code works fine without br.close(). Is there some concept of BufferedReader that I am missing?

```
 public String readString() throws IOException {
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
   String s="";
   s=br.readLine();
   br.close();
   return s;

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
Test obj = new Test();
String one = obj.readString();
String two = obj.readString();

}
```

Comment: [Couldn't reproduce](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/hsV0fhGyA8PMlMVy).

Comment: Never close `System.in` or a Reader that uses it. That's a very dangerous thing to do, and has been addressed here many times.

Comment: Instead create your BufferedReader or Scanner and pass it to where it's needed.

Comment: Oh. Thank you. I was not aware of that. Is there a better way to do it? I thought we are supposed to close the BufferedReader once we are done with it. I'm not too much into programming.

Comment: Yes, close it when you the application is *completely* done with `System.in` but not before. `System.in` is somewhat special.